# How do I copy music to my iPhone using iTunes 11?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, ipod

I've always managed my iPhone/iPad/iPod Manually, I recently updated to iTunes 11 and now I can see no way to get my music onto my device.

I used to be able to just drag songs from my library to my device, now there is seemingly no way to do this.

I can view the music on my device by clicking on it on the top right corner of iTunes, but I can't seem to get to a state where I can drag music from my computer onto my device.

I'm using iTunes 11.0.1.12 for Windows if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start draging arround tracks or albums there should open at the right a bar within your iPhone/iPad/iPod. Drag the track/album on it.

Comment: Awesome! That works so much better than creating a play list.

Answer (score 2):

1. find the very top left control button
2. click on the downward point triangle next to the control button
3. click Show Menu Bar on the drop down menu
4. on the Menu Bar click on View
5. click on Show Sidebar on the drop down menu
6. now you should be able to see your device on the left side bar
7. drag your music to your device as you please.

Answer (score 2):

I got it by clicking on the iDevice towards the upper-right, under the Info tab scroll down and check the box to Manually manage music. It will warn you that it needs to erase the library on your iDevice, proceed knowing that it will clear your music off your iDevice but you can then copy the music from your computer's iTunes library back on to your iDevice.
Worked with my iPhone 4 6.0.1 iTunes 11 Windows XP

Answer (score -1):

Check the box Manually manage music and videos

Comment: Isn't this what the OP mentioned that he has done? Would you mind adding more details?